# Need advice: SignalR support for Windows XP (.NET 4.0)

Tags: .net-4.0, signalr, signalr.client

I am developing some kind of communication and data-interchange system to use in various applications that my company is producing. There will be SignalR hub for messaging and WCF service for file streaming.

I was thinking of developing a Hub library in .NET 4.5. Also I plan to enable Hub hosting in some windows process and IIS.

Thing that bothers me is that I have to support Windows XP clients, so I cannot use .NET 4.5 for developing a client library.

My question is: Are there bad effects of providing a .NET 4.0 client library for all clients, even though there are more clients with Windows 7 or Windows 8? My concern is about performance and features - am I going to lose any of that if I go with .NET 4.0 client?

Comment: You won't get websocket transport on windows 8 clients.

Comment: So the SignalR won't dinamically decide which type of transport should use depending on client type. So if I am using .NET 4.0, SignalR library will use polling or something other type of transport.

Comment: It will but since .NET Framework 4 doesn't have the ClientWebsocket class SignalR client will only try ServerSentEvents and if this doesn't work LongPolling